# React migration to hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I started a new job and here the client is written in react. The big problem is that everything is very old and uses classes instead of React hooks. One simple example of an issue is the need to use mobx 6 or higher however this will require going over all the classes removing the @observable and changing it to make it observable. I don't even know how to start transitioning to a newer version of React with hooks since there is no way of doing it gradually only all at once. In any case if someone can help me with a suggestion or what can be done I will appreciated very much here is dependencies in my package.json if it's of any help

```
  "dependencies": {
"babel-plugin-react-intl": "~3.0.1",
"babel-plugin-wildcard": "~2.1.2",
"bestzip": "^2.2.0",
"bootstrap": "~4.2.1",
"classnames": "~2.2.6",
"config": "~1.27.0",
"coreui.io": "^1.0.0-alpha.6",
"cross-env": "~5.2.0",
"event-emitter-es6": "~1.1.5",
"font-awesome": "~4.7.0",
"js-file-download": "~0.4.4",
"jsx-control-statements": "~3.2.8",
"lodash": "~4.17.4",
"mobx-react-intl": "~1.4.0",
"moment": "~2.20.1",
"papaparse": "~4.3.7",
"preact-context": "~1.1.2",
"query-string": "~6.1.0",
"react": "16.8.0",
"react-app-polyfill": "~0.2.0",
"react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
"react-bootstrap-table": "~4.3.1",
"react-dates": "~20.0.0",
"react-dom": "16.8.0",
"react-fast-compare": "~2.0.4",
"react-fontawesome": "~1.6.1",
"react-google-charts": "~3.0.11",
"react-inlinesvg": "~0.6.2",
"react-interval": "~2.0.2",
"react-intl": "~2.8.0",
"react-json-view": "^1.19.1",
"react-ladda": "~6.0.0",
"react-rangeslider": "~2.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "~4.3.1",
"react-select": "~1.2.1",
"react-smooth-range-input": "~0.2.4",
"react-transition-group": "~1.2.1",
"reactstrap": "~7.1.0",
"shx": "^0.3.3",
"simple-line-icons": "~2.4.1",
"superagent": "~3.8.0",
"superagent-auth-bearer": "~0.0.1",
"svgo": "~1.0.3",
"three2": "npm:three@0.125.2",
"webpack-cli": "~3.2.1"
```

},

```
  "devDependencies": {
"babel": "~6",
"babel-cli": "~6.24.1",
"babel-eslint": "~10.0.1",
"babel-loader": "~7.1.1",
"babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes": "~3.3.0",
"babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "~6.13.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "~1.3.4",
"babel-polyfill": "~6.23.0",
"babel-preset-env": "~1.6.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "~6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "~6.24.1",
"babel-preset-stage-1": "~6.24.1",
"babel-preset-stage-2": "~6.24.1",
"babili-webpack-plugin": "~0.1.2",
"cobertura-merge": "*",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "~4.6.0",
"css-hot-loader": "~1.3.0",
"css-loader": "~2.1.0",
"eslint": "~4.4.1",
"eslint-config-wix": "~1.1.16",
"eslint-loader": "~1.9.0",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~4.0.0-beta.0",
"file-loader": "~3.0.1",
"flow-bin": "~0.48.0",
"flow-status-webpack-plugin": "~0.1.7",
"html-webpack-plugin": "~3.2.0",
"install": "~0.10.1",
"jest": "~20.0.4",
"jest-cli": "~20",
"jest-html-reporters": "^1.2.1",
"jest-junit": "*",
"mobx": "~5.9.0",
"mobx-react": "~5.4.3",
"mobx-react-devtools": "~4.2.15",
"node-sass": "~4.14.0",
"nodemon": "~1.11.0",
"npm": "~5.3.0",
"optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "~3.1.1",
"preact": "~10.0.0-alpha.0",
"preact-compat": "~3.18.4",
"react-c3js": "~0.1.20",
"resolve-url": "~0.2.1",
"resolve-url-loader": "~3.0.0",
"sass-loader": "~7.1.0",
"style-loader": "~0.18.2",
"svg-react-loader": "~0.4.6",
"url-loader": "~1.1.2",
"webpack": "~4.29.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "~3.1.14",
"webpack-merge": "~4.1.0"
```

},

Comment: This is a very vague question and thus answering is difficult. I can not see any codes, therefore helping in the sense of generalization is not competent.

Comment: why can't you transition gradually? current version react still supports class components

Comment: You are right I guess how ever it is hard than it looks. For example I have a class that uses at_observable at_inject (actually I have 181 of those). Now let's say I want to switch to hooks I will mobx-react:6+ but this does not support at_observable thus I need to go over 181 classes and change the behavior

Comment: It looks like mobx-react 6 still supports class components. Are you asking how to deal with breaking changes in a particular library? Because that's not really a "class component/functional component" concern.

Comment: Just a heads up: I see `preact` v10 in your dependencies and `preact-compat`. `preact-compat` is only for v8 and below of `preact`. It doesn't work on v10. That functionality has been moved to `preact/compat`. See: https://github.com/preactjs/preact-compat/

Comment: @rschristian Thank does that mean that I will need to change the code even more or is simply changing a dependency will do?

Comment: You just need to remove `preact-compat` and make sure you're setting your aliases to `preact/compat` instead. Compat still exists, it's just been moved.